# Prove there is no integer $m$ such that $3x^2+4x+m$ is a factor of $6x^4+50$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, polynomials

Prove there is no integer $m$ such that $3x^2+4x+m$ is a factor of $6x^4+50$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

I understand that I will need to use the division algorithm on polynomials, however I am confused why $m$ excludes $3x^2+4x+m$ as a factor. I found the division of these polynomials will yield fractional coefficients which are not in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, thus no integer $m$ will make $3x^2+4x+m$ a factor. Is this the correct train of thought?

Comment: Or you might observe that if it were a factor, it would have to be the case that $6x^2 + 50 = n(3x^2 + 4x + m)$, for some integer $n$. Which is absurd

Comment: Perhaps you mean $3x^3$ or some other higher power?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that.  I meant $6x^4$ and have changed the question.

Answer (score 2):

$ \begin{align}{\bf Hint}\quad  {\rm mod}\ 3\!:\ \  & (3x^2\!+\!4x\!+\!m)\,(2x^2\!+\!bx\!+\!c)\\ 
&\equiv\ \ \ \ \, (x+m)\,(2x^2+\cdots)\\ 
& \equiv  \  \ 2\,x^{\large\color{#c00}3}+\,\cdots  \end{align} $

$\, 6x^4\!+50\,\equiv 50\ $ has degree $< \color{#c00}3\ $ so they cannot be equal.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $\;6x^4+50 = 0\;$ has $4$ complex roots, and for each one $\;|x_j| = \sqrt[4]{50/6}=\sqrt{5}/\sqrt[4]{3}\;$.

If $3x^2+4x+m$ is a factor of $6x^4+50$ then its two complex roots will be among $x_j \mid j=1 \dots 4$. By Vieta's formulas their product $x_j x_k=m/3 \implies |x_j x_k|=5 / \sqrt{3} = |m/3|$. But $5 / \sqrt{3}$ is irrational, so there exists no $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $5 / \sqrt{3} = |m/3|$.

Comment: Wish the downvoter cared to explain.